# Using let created variables in other fitnesse fixtures

Tags: testing, fitnesse

I have a problem with using *let* created variables. 
I'm using RestFixture to get/post from http location and I do want to use this answer in another fixture:

1. I'm getting data via post
2. saving body as variable using *let*
3. printing my variable in comment line to see that is really working

|!-CustomRestFixture-!|http://addres |CONFIG|
|setHeader |Content-Type : application/json |
|setBody    | {some JSON body} |
|POST      |                  |200 |Content-Type: text/plain    |             |
|let       |myvariable        |body|//*                         |             |
|comment                      | This is my variable  : %myvariable%           |

4. Then I would like to use it in another (custom made) fixture that compares two strings (second fixture is inside same test page) :

!|DecTable|
|my first value|my second value|is this equal?|
|aaa           |aaa            |true          |
|%myvariable%  |anything       |ture          |

5. What I can noticed is my variable is not working anywhere else that in RestFixture. I can not pass is any further, but it suppose to be global

Is there any solution for that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of the `let` keyword of RestFixture. But you can use variables using the [standard Slim approach to define 'symbols'](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables) from decision/script tables. These symbols can then be used in any fixture.

Using [my fixture library](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) you could combine a [(Json) Http Test](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/2.-Slim-Fixtures#httptest) and [Compare Fixture](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/acceptance-test-results/HsacAcceptanceTests.SlimTests.UtilityFixtures.CompareFixtureTest.html) to achieve what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are global and can be shared across rest fixture instances.

However, if you want to use labels in your own custom fixture, you can save the data in to a variable like below and use it in any other custom fixtures

```
|let|card_number1|js |response.jsonbody.card.number|$card=|
```

This would save card number in to a variable that is globally available to use in other tables

one point I would like to remind you though is that you don't have to write a separate fixture to compare the response from rest fixture. You can access the content of your response using response.jsonbody.element1 if you have json response and /root/element1/text() if you have an xml response. So both posting a request at an end-point and validation can be done all in 1 go. An example is below

```
|Table: RestFixture|${protocol}://${baseuri}:${port}/${resource_path}|longtimeoutconfig                                                                     |    
|setBody                                          |$req0                                                                                                                                   |
|setHeader                                        |Content-Type: application/json                                                                                                          |
|POST                                             |                                                 |200|                                                   |                    |
|let                                              |amount1                                          |js |response.jsonbody.amount                           |${amount}                     |
```

some very good examples can be found at https://cloud.github.com/downloads/smartrics/RestFixture/RestFixture-3.0.pdf

Comment: The latest version of usage examples and documentation is [available in the RestFixtureLiveDoc](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixtureLiveDoc/tree/master/src/main/resources/FitNesseRoot/RestFixtureTests) project on GitHub